# I have created a 5Ghz wireless ap on my raspberry pi 4 but it is not upto the speed of 5Ghz

Tags: wifi, pi-4, access-point

Link speed is only 72mbps i have tested in several devices link speed from rpi4 is 72mbps from other 5ghz sources it is high.
iperf3 also results in around 60mbps (mega bits per second) speed.

This is my hostapd.conf file

```
country_code=IN
interface=wlan0
ssid=Pi
hw_mode=a
channel=40
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=password
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP

beacon_int=100
driver=nl80211
vht_capab=[HT40+]
ieee80211ac=1
wmm_enabled=1
ctrl_interface_group=0
```

Can anyone suggest any solution to this problem ?
what can i do to improve these speeds ?

Comment: How do you measure the speed? If you test this using file transfer, the most likely cause is that the SD card in the Pi is not up to the task. More than 70Mbytes/sec is unlikely to be achievable.

Comment: as already mentioned i have used `iperf3`

also the link speed is 72Mbits/sec which is being displayed in android device and windows 10.

Comment: What speed do you expect?

Comment: What speed can i expect ? I mean 5GHz band have Theoretical Max Speed of around 1.7 Gbps so I can expect a real world speed of atleast 400-500 Mbps. is that not possible with rpi 4 ?